# Как определить установлен ли пакет?

Tags: пакет, unix, solaris, ssh, linux

Необходимо определить установлены ли пакеты c `zlib` и `openssl`. `aptitude` отсутствует и невозможно установить пока что по определенным причинам, поэтому вариант, предлагавшийся на http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5794/linux-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-nexenta отпадает, да и `zlib` и `openssl` могли устанавливаться вручную. Эти программы необходимы для установки `openssh` (см. ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL), поэтому конечно можно просто попытаться установить его и если система выдаст ошибку на отсутствие таких программ, то значит, они не установлены, но хотелось бы это выяснить все таки перед попыткой установки `openssh`.

P.S. [[@Anton Shevtsov](/users/3274/anton-shevtsov)](/users/3274/anton-shevtsov) В результате выполнения скрипта `./configure` я получил следующий результат (помогите расшифровать относительно вопроса, который я задал, да и вообще необходима информация, что из указанного на ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL необходимо установить, я новичок в `Linux`, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием)

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/gnu/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/gnu/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/gnu/bin/install -c
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/gnu/bin/grep -E
checking for ar... /usr/gnu/bin/ar
checking for cat... /usr/gnu/bin/cat
checking for kill... /usr/gnu/bin/kill
checking for perl5... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for sed... /usr/gnu/bin/sed
checking for ent... no
checking for bash... /usr/bin/bash
checking for ksh... (cached) /usr/bin/bash
checking for sh... (cached) /usr/bin/bash
checking for sh... /usr/gnu/bin/sh
checking for groff... /usr/bin/groff
checking for nroff... /usr/gnu/bin/nroff
checking for mandoc... no
checking for groupadd... /usr/sbin/groupadd
checking for useradd... /usr/sbin/useradd
checking for pkgmk... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking for login... /usr/bin/login
checking for passwd... /usr/bin/passwd
checking for inline... inline
checking whether LLONG_MAX is declared... yes
checking whether SYSTR_POLICY_KILL is declared... no
checking whether RLIMIT_NPROC is declared... no
checking whether PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS is declared... no
checking if gcc supports -Wall... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wuninitialized... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wsign-compare... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wformat-security... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wpointer-sign... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wunused-result... no
checking if gcc supports -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking if gcc supports -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2... yes
checking gcc version... 4.4.4
checking if gcc accepts -fno-builtin-memset... yes
checking if gcc supports -fstack-protector-all... yes
checking if -fstack-protector-all works... yes
checking bstring.h usability... no
checking bstring.h presence... no
checking for bstring.h... no
checking crypt.h usability... yes
checking crypt.h presence... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking crypto/sha2.h usability... no
checking crypto/sha2.h presence... no
checking for crypto/sha2.h... no
checking dirent.h usability... yes
checking dirent.h presence... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking endian.h usability... no
checking endian.h presence... no
checking for endian.h... no
checking features.h usability... no
checking features.h presence... no
checking for features.h... no
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking floatingpoint.h usability... no
checking floatingpoint.h presence... no
checking for floatingpoint.h... no
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking glob.h usability... yes
checking glob.h presence... yes
checking for glob.h... yes
checking ia.h usability... no
checking ia.h presence... no
checking for ia.h... no
checking iaf.h usability... no
checking iaf.h presence... no
checking for iaf.h... no
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking login.h usability... no
checking login.h presence... no
checking for login.h... no
checking maillock.h usability... yes
checking maillock.h presence... yes
checking for maillock.h... yes
checking ndir.h usability... no
checking ndir.h presence... no
checking for ndir.h... no
checking net/if_tun.h usability... no
checking net/if_tun.h presence... no
checking for net/if_tun.h... no
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netgroup.h usability... no
checking netgroup.h presence... no
checking for netgroup.h... no
checking pam/pam_appl.h usability... no
checking pam/pam_appl.h presence... no
checking for pam/pam_appl.h... no
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking pty.h usability... no
checking pty.h presence... no
checking for pty.h... no
checking readpassphrase.h usability... no
checking readpassphrase.h presence... no
checking for readpassphrase.h... no
checking rpc/types.h usability... yes
checking rpc/types.h presence... yes
checking for rpc/types.h... yes
checking security/pam_appl.h usability... yes
checking security/pam_appl.h presence... yes
checking for security/pam_appl.h... yes
checking sha2.h usability... yes
checking sha2.h presence... yes
checking for sha2.h... yes
checking shadow.h usability... yes
checking shadow.h presence... yes
checking for shadow.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/audit.h usability... no
checking sys/audit.h presence... no
checking for sys/audit.h... no
checking sys/bitypes.h usability... no
checking sys/bitypes.h presence... no
checking for sys/bitypes.h... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h usability... no
checking sys/bsdtty.h presence... no
checking for sys/bsdtty.h... no
checking sys/cdefs.h usability... no
checking sys/cdefs.h presence... no
checking for sys/cdefs.h... no
checking sys/dir.h usability... no
checking sys/dir.h presence... no
checking for sys/dir.h... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking sys/ndir.h usability... no
checking sys/ndir.h presence... no
checking for sys/ndir.h... no
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking sys/prctl.h usability... no
checking sys/prctl.h presence... no
checking for sys/prctl.h... no
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/stream.h usability... yes
checking sys/stream.h presence... yes
checking for sys/stream.h... yes
checking sys/stropts.h usability... yes
checking sys/stropts.h presence... yes
checking for sys/stropts.h... yes
checking sys/strtio.h usability... no
checking sys/strtio.h presence... no
checking for sys/strtio.h... no
checking sys/statvfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/timers.h usability... no
checking sys/timers.h presence... no
checking for sys/timers.h... no
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking tmpdir.h usability... no
checking tmpdir.h presence... no
checking for tmpdir.h... no
checking ttyent.h usability... no
checking ttyent.h presence... no
checking for ttyent.h... no
checking ucred.h usability... yes
checking ucred.h presence... yes
checking for ucred.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking usersec.h usability... no
checking usersec.h presence... no
checking for usersec.h... no
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking utmp.h usability... yes
checking utmp.h presence... yes
checking for utmp.h... yes
checking utmpx.h usability... yes
checking utmpx.h presence... yes
checking for utmpx.h... yes
checking vis.h usability... no
checking vis.h presence... no
checking for vis.h... no
checking for lastlog.h... yes
checking for sys/ptms.h... yes
checking for login_cap.h... no
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for obsolete utmp and wtmp in solaris2.x... yes
checking compiler and flags for sanity... yes
checking for yp_match... no
checking for yp_match in -lnsl... yes
checking for setsockopt... no
checking for setsockopt in -lsocket... yes
checking for dirname... yes
checking libgen.h usability... yes
checking libgen.h presence... yes
checking for libgen.h... yes
checking for getspnam... yes
checking for library containing basename... none required
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for deflate in -lz... yes
checking for possibly buggy zlib... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for utimes... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking for library containing fmt_scaled... no
checking for library containing login... no
checking for library containing logout... no
checking for library containing logwtmp... no
checking for library containing openpty... no
checking for library containing updwtmp... none required
checking for fmt_scaled... no
checking for login... no
checking for logout... no
checking for openpty... no
checking for updwtmp... yes
checking for logwtmp... no
checking for strftime... yes
checking for GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC support... no
checking for gl_matchc field in glob_t... no
checking for gl_statv and GLOB_KEEPSTAT extensions for glob... no
checking whether GLOB_NOMATCH is declared... yes
checking whether struct dirent allocates space for d_name... no
checking for /proc/pid/fd directory... yes
checking for arc4random... no
checking for arc4random_buf... no
checking for arc4random_uniform... no
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for b64_ntop... no
checking for __b64_ntop... no
checking for b64_pton... no
checking for __b64_pton... no
checking for bcopy... yes
checking for bindresvport_sa... no
checking for clock... yes
checking for closefrom... yes
checking for dirfd... yes
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for fchown... yes
checking for freeaddrinfo... yes
checking for fstatvfs... yes
checking for futimes... no
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getgrouplist... no
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking for getopt... yes
checking for getpeereid... no
checking for getpeerucred... yes
checking for _getpty... no
checking for getrlimit... yes
checking for getttyent... no
checking for glob... yes
checking for group_from_gid... no
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for inet_ntop... yes
checking for innetgr... yes
checking for login_getcapbool... no
checking for md5_crypt... no
checking for memmove... yes
checking for mkdtemp... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for ngetaddrinfo... no
checking for nsleep... no
checking for ogetaddrinfo... no
checking for openlog_r... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for prctl... no
checking for pstat... no
checking for readpassphrase... no
checking for realpath... yes
checking for recvmsg... yes
checking for rresvport_af... yes
checking for sendmsg... yes
checking for setdtablesize... no
checking for setegid... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for seteuid... yes
checking for setgroupent... no
checking for setgroups... yes
checking for setlinebuf... yes
checking for setlogin... no
checking for setpassent... no
checking for setpcred... no
checking for setproctitle... no
checking for setregid... yes
checking for setreuid... yes
checking for setrlimit... yes
checking for setsid... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigvec... no
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for strmode... no
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strnvis... no
checking for strptime... yes
checking for strtonum... no
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for swap32... no
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for timingsafe_bcmp... no
checking for truncate... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for updwtmpx... yes
checking for user_from_uid... no
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for vhangup... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for library containing dlopen... none required
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for library containing nanosleep... none required
checking whether getrusage is declared... no
checking whether strsep is declared... yes
checking for strsep... yes
checking whether tcsendbreak is declared... yes
checking whether h_errno is declared... yes
checking whether SHUT_RD is declared... yes
checking whether O_NONBLOCK is declared... yes
checking whether writev is declared... yes
checking whether MAXSYMLINKS is declared... yes
checking whether offsetof is declared... yes
checking for setresuid... no
checking for setresgid... no
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for time... yes
checking for endutent... yes
checking for getutent... yes
checking for getutid... yes
checking for getutline... yes
checking for pututline... yes
checking for setutent... yes
checking for utmpname... yes
checking for endutxent... yes
checking for getutxent... yes
checking for getutxid... yes
checking for getutxline... yes
checking for getutxuser... no
checking for pututxline... yes
checking for setutxdb... no
checking for setutxent... yes
checking for utmpxname... yes
checking for getlastlogxbyname... no
checking for daemon... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking whether snprintf correctly terminates long strings... yes
checking whether snprintf can declare const char *fmt... yes
checking for (overly) strict mkstemp... no
checking whether getpgrp requires zero arguments... yes
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)
checking OpenSSL library version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... yes
checking if programs using OpenSSL functions will link... yes
checking for RSA_generate_key_ex... yes
checking for DSA_generate_parameters_ex... yes
checking for BN_is_prime_ex... yes
checking for RSA_get_default_method... yes
checking for HMAC_CTX_init... yes
checking whether OpenSSL has crippled AES support... no
checking if EVP_DigestUpdate returns an int... yes
checking for SHA256_Update... yes
checking for EVP_sha256... yes
checking whether OpenSSL has complete ECC support... no
checking for ia_openinfo in -liaf... no
checking whether OpenSSL's PRNG is internally seeded... yes
checking if select works with descriptor rlimit... no
checking if setrlimit RLIMIT_FSIZE works... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking for unsigned long long... yes
checking for long double... yes
checking size of short int... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long int... 4
checking size of long long int... 8
checking for u_int type... yes
checking for intXX_t types... yes
checking for int64_t type... yes
checking for u_intXX_t types... no
checking for u_intXX_t types in sys/socket.h... no
checking for u_int64_t types... no
checking for u_int64_t type in sys/bitypes.h... no
checking for uintXX_t types... yes
checking for uintXX_t types in stdint.h... yes
checking for u_char... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for sig_atomic_t... yes
checking for fsblkcnt_t... yes
checking for fsfilcnt_t... yes
checking for in_addr_t... yes
checking for in_port_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for clock_t... yes
checking for sa_family_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_in6... yes
checking for struct in6_addr... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_in6.sin6_scope_id... yes
checking for struct addrinfo... yes
checking for struct timeval... yes
checking for struct timespec... yes
checking for ut_host field in utmp.h... no
checking for ut_host field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for syslen field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for ut_pid field in utmp.h... yes
checking for ut_type field in utmp.h... yes
checking for ut_type field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for ut_tv field in utmp.h... no
checking for ut_id field in utmp.h... yes
checking for ut_id field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for ut_addr field in utmp.h... no
checking for ut_addr field in utmpx.h... no
checking for ut_addr_v6 field in utmp.h... no
checking for ut_addr_v6 field in utmpx.h... no
checking for ut_exit field in utmp.h... yes
checking for ut_time field in utmp.h... yes
checking for ut_time field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for ut_tv field in utmpx.h... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct __res_state.retrans... yes
checking for ss_family field in struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for __ss_family field in struct sockaddr_storage... no
checking for pw_class field in struct passwd... no
checking for pw_expire field in struct passwd... no
checking for pw_change field in struct passwd... no
checking for msg_accrights field in struct msghdr... yes
checking if struct statvfs.f_fsid is integral type... yes
checking for msg_control field in struct msghdr... no
checking if libc defines __progname... yes
checking whether gcc implements __FUNCTION__... yes
checking whether gcc implements __func__... yes
checking whether va_copy exists... yes
checking whether __va_copy exists... yes
checking whether getopt has optreset support... no
checking if libc defines sys_errlist... yes
checking if libc defines sys_nerr... yes
checking for library containing getrrsetbyname... no
checking for library containing res_query... -lresolv
checking for library containing dn_expand... none required
checking if res_query will link... yes
checking for _getshort... yes
checking for _getlong... yes
checking whether _getshort is declared... no
checking whether _getlong is declared... no
checking for HEADER.ad... no
checking if struct __res_state _res is an extern... yes
checking for xauth... no
checking Discovering system mail directory... Using: /var/mail from _PATH_MAILDIR
checking for "/dev/ptmx"... yes
checking for "/dev/ptc"... no
checking for nroff... (cached) /usr/gnu/bin/nroff
checking if the systems has expire shadow information... yes
checking for "/etc/default/login"... yes
configure: WARNING:
If PATH is defined in /etc/default/login, ensure the path to scp is included,
otherwise scp will not work.
Adding /usr/local/bin to USER_PATH so scp will work
checking if we need to convert IPv4 in IPv6-mapped addresses... no (default)
checking if your system defines LASTLOG_FILE... no
checking if your system defines _PATH_LASTLOG... no
checking if your system defines UTMP_FILE... yes
checking if your system defines WTMP_FILE... yes
checking if your system defines WTMPX_FILE... yes
checking whether BROKEN_GETADDRINFO is declared... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating buildpkg.sh
config.status: creating opensshd.init
config.status: creating openssh.xml
config.status: creating openbsd-compat/Makefile
config.status: creating openbsd-compat/regress/Makefile
config.status: creating survey.sh
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged

OpenSSH has been configured with the following options:
                     User binaries: /usr/local/bin
                   System binaries: /usr/local/sbin
               Configuration files: /usr/local/etc
                   Askpass program: /usr/local/libexec/ssh-askpass
                      Manual pages: /usr/local/share/man/manX
                          PID file: /var/run
  Privilege separation chroot path: /var/empty
            sshd default user PATH: /usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
   (If PATH is set in /etc/default/login it will be used instead. If
   used, ensure the path to scp is present, otherwise scp will not work.)
                    Manpage format: doc
                       PAM support: no
                   OSF SIA support: no
                 KerberosV support: no
                   SELinux support: no
                 Smartcard support: 
                     S/KEY support: no
              TCP Wrappers support: no
              MD5 password support: no
                   libedit support: no
  Solaris process contract support: no
           Solaris project support: no
       IP address in $DISPLAY hack: no
           Translate v4 in v6 hack: no
                  BSD Auth support: no
              Random number source: OpenSSL internal ONLY
             Privsep sandbox style: none

              Host: i386-pc-solaris2.11
          Compiler: gcc
    Compiler flags: -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all 
Preprocessor flags: 
      Linker flags:  -fstack-protector-all
         Libraries: -lresolv -lcrypto -lz -lsocket -lnsl

SVR4 style packages are supported with "make package"
```

Привожу строки с 'zlib' и `openssl`

```
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for possibly buggy zlib... no
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)
checking OpenSSL library version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... yes
checking if programs using OpenSSL functions will link... yes
checking whether OpenSSL has crippled AES support... no
checking whether OpenSSL has complete ECC support... no
checking whether OpenSSL's PRNG is internally seeded... yes
Random number source: OpenSSL internal ONLY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если на стадии ./configure не ругается ни на что то установлен :)

Comment: @AntonShevtsov а без действий по установке `openssh` можно ли определить установлены ли пакеты?

Comment: ну ./configure никаких действий не делает.. только проверка системы..
не зная вашей системы ничего сказать не могу.. типа такого 
    
    ldconfig -p | grep -i libz
    ldconfig -p | grep -i libssl

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov а не могли бы вы прокомментировать команды и опции к ним ?

Comment: ./configure - проверяет наличие необходимых модулей, библиотек и прочего зависимого софта для сборки.

на вашем уровне достаточно ориентироваться на yes/no напротив искомых либов. В данном случае zlib, openssl установлен.